# Xamarin Forms UWP - Display PDF

Tags: pdf, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

Please, help me and tell me what am I missing.

My goal is to **display simple PDF file** (stored locally for example) **in the WebView control**. Can I bind path of the file to the Source property of the WebView? Or what is the correct way to show PDF in UWP?

P.S. and if the only option is to do like [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/) - how must I add **pdf.js** to my project??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to display simple PDF file (stored locally for example) in the WebView control.

If you want to display pdf in `WebView` control, then the methods in [Display a Local PDF File in a WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/) is most like the only way to solve your problem.

You can follow the steps in the xamarin official document, and here are some additional tips we need to pay attention to:

1. After downloading [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download), for UWP app, you need to copy the entire folder into the `Assets` folder, make sure that the folder is named "pdfjs", otherwise you will need to modify the code to change the path.
2. Your .pdf file should be stored into the `Content` folder under the `Assets` folder, it means you will need to create a new folder named "Content" under `Assets` and copy your .pdf file into this folder. Otherwise, you will also need to modify the code to change the path.
3. After copying your .pdf file into the "Content" folder, don't forget to change the `Build Action` of this file to `Content` like this:

[image]

> Or what is the correct way to show PDF in UWP?

In uwp app, you can use `Image` to show PDF file, you can refer to the official [PDF document sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/PdfDocument). But I don't know if PDF can be displayed as Image in Android and IOS apps, since you're developing a cross-platform project, I think it's better to use the built-in method to solve such problem.

If a demo for xamarin UWP is needed, you can leave a comment, I will upload my demo later.

Comment: Tnanks, this was helpful! Btw, can PDFJS viewer open not only files that are located at the Assets folder?

For example:

`var uriString = "ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=ms-appdata:///local/Test/test.pdf";

Control.Navigate(new Uri(uriString));`