# display local PDF file in webview control - Displays Blank Pdf File

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am working on Xamarin Forms - UWP.
I want to display local PDF file in webview control. I followed these 2 links :-
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/

[Xamarin Forms UWP - Display PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379475/xamarin-forms-uwp-display-pdf/44705423#44705423)

It opens the pdf file but content is all blank.
Can anyone please help me in what I may be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:-
CustomWebView.cs

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
                defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }
    }


<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PdfViewer;assembly=PdfViewer"
         x:Class="PdfViewer.MainPage"
         Padding="0,20,0,0">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:CustomWebView Uri="samplepdf.pdf" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfViewer.CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace PdfViewer.UWP
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                Control.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Assets/Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[UWP - Assets - pdfjs structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmSx5.png)

Comment: how we can help if you didn't provide any of your code but just links of how it suppose to work?

Comment: public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
                defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }
    }

Comment: Make sure file build action is set to Content. Check that your Uri pointing to file is correct.

Comment: I have already changed it to Content, still it is coming blank. Btw I am trying to upload the code but it is asking me to format it which i believe is already formated.

Comment: I have uploaded my code and an image file to show the folder structure of the pdf.js and content folder

Comment: Did you try to download sample project from the link you provided https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/ and run it?

Comment: no I didn't download the project. I created my project.

Comment: I didn't ask about your project, I asked about sample project from the page. If it works on your machine can you figure out what you are doing wrong in you project?

Comment: Did you add "viewer" files? html, js?

Comment: "Viewer" files you mean under pdfjs->web->viewer.html, viewer.js, viewer.css. Yes I have added that as it came under pdfjs.

Comment: ok, I copied all necessary files from GitHub and got it working. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the problem. May be you are missing some files - there are a lot of them and I didn't check what is really necessary. Did you copy everything from github from pdfjs folder including subfolders? The only thing I can suggest to help you if you did is to do teamviewer session with you and try to figure out what is wrong on you PC. Sorry, that's all I can do

Comment: BTW, what does it mean Content is blank? Do you see the frame of pdf viewer or the window is completely blank?

Comment: To answer the second question first:- I see the frame of the pdf viewer and all it's controls but doesn't show any pages.

Comment: Now the answer to the first question:- I downloaded the pdfjs folder from the link provided in the recipe and copied all code from the github. Regarding teamviewer , i will install first as i have never used it before. then will let u know. Thx

Comment: if you see the frame make sure that "I10n.js" is there and has Content Build action. Without it you will get the frame but not content. Also verify again files exist and set to Content: "pdf.worker.js" and "pdf.js"

Comment: Can you provide your project structure screenshot starting with everything under Assets folder

Comment: And last stupid question. Is your pdf file in Content folder?

Comment: @Yuri, I have installed TeamViewer. When can we have Remote sharing so that you can have a look. thx

Comment: Yes my pdf is under Content Folder. I will provide you the screenshot in a minute

Comment: do you know how to create chat room?

Comment: go to chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147484/xamarin-pdf-viewer

Comment: just a stupid question. i can see the chat room but I don't know how to reply on that :(

Comment: there is a text box in the bootom of the room, type there :-)

Comment: it's disabled. "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: I created a new account so may be it's not allowing me to chat. If it is possible to talk over the email or someother way is there. :(

Comment: checking how to do that...

Comment: can you type now? If not do you have Skype?

Comment: sent you request on Skype

Comment: I placed a comment but it got deleted, if you have any updates on this (I got the exact same problem) please help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something happened with Asset folder files. When was updated from nuget repository it worked.

Comment: thanks for all your help. You saved my one more day struggling to figure out where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the similar issue when I implement a [`HybridWebView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/) following the official document.

The problem is that the [build action](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images) property of PDF file is not `Content`.
Please set the build action as `Content` within your uwp client project.

[image]

Comment: I have already changed the build action to Content. still it is showing blank content. Is the naming convention of the file wrong? I know the proper naming convention is required in Android.