# Xamarin displays blank PDF in custom webviewer

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin

I am currently busy with a Xamarin mobile application (only android now) and I am trying to show PDF files. I found a free plugin here: https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf but I run into an issue.

When I go to the view I see the PDF controls, but not the PDF itself. (shows a gray screen). Here is a similar issue: [display local PDF file in webview control - Displays Blank Pdf File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705923/display-local-pdf-file-in-webview-control-displays-blank-pdf-file/) but nothing is working.

I put the PDF file in the correct place with the correct options, see here:
[image: Screenshot Visual Studio showing the correct options]

And here you can see the view in the emulator:
[image: Screenshot mobile emulator showing blank PDF but with the controls]

I also tried the run the given demo project, but I get a lot of errors :(
Some help would be really appreciated!

CustomView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BizzTimeTest.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomPDFWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
                returnType: typeof(string),
                declaringType: typeof(CustomPDFWebView),
                defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom renderer:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using BizzTimeTest.Droid;
using BizzTimeTest.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPDFWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace BizzTimeTest.Droid
{
    [Obsolete]
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomPDFWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", "test_pdf_file.pdf")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<local:CustomPDFWebView x:Name="custom_pdf_viewer" IsVisible="false" 
Uri="test_pdf_file.pdf" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Comment: We can't help you because we don' t know what you're doing.  You haven't posted ANY code for us to review.  And how are we supposed to know what "but I get a lot of errors" means?  What errors?  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing a good on-topic question.

Comment: Well I posted what I was doing and what the problem is, a blank PDF. That part about the errors is related to the demo project, but I don't want to fix those errors, I want to fix the PDF viewer. I used the code given in the sample, and as stated in the other stackoverflow thread: the code is correct but still it doesn't show up. It's probably a visual studio thing and perhaps people have the same result.

Comment: Did you set the pdf files's build action to AndroidAsset ?

Comment: Hey @LeoZhu-MSFT I put it as content because I read that in some other thread - I tried all the options, but I will check again

Comment: @RolandMakkelie were you able to solve it? Facing same issue.